# bad unicode strings

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, character-encoding

I have a mysql database with utf8 charset set, but i have a lot of rows in a table with text like this:

```
War leider sehr entt\u00e4uscht.
```

Instead of:

```
War leider sehr enttäuscht.
```

I'm trying to fix it with python but when I read them, it returns:

```
War leider sehr entt\\u00e4uscht.
```

I tried to encode it to utf8 with .encode("utf-8") but the result is the same.

One thing i tried is replacing all utf character like:

```
body.replace("\\u00e4","\u00e4")
```

Is there another approach? instead of replacing all characters?
Thanks in advice

Comment: Are you trying to prevent Unicode codepoint representation?  And/or fix the data?  Here are some random tips for using UTF8 with Python:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I achieve it with:

```
 codecs.decode(body, 'unicode-escape')
```